# openni2 launcher issue

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i try to launch "roslaunch openni2_launch openni2_launch" command, this command is for the kinect but the openni1 command doesn't open or connect to the usb interface.But the openni2 can connect to the asus kinect (primesense) it can detect the usb interface without any errors. In the rviz software there is no images and also the camera together with
Openni2 launch.
Openni2 camera.

how to solve the kinect issue, please help me with the kinect issue please thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151791/openni2-launcher-issue/) by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni2 supports xtion devices, but not kinects.
For using a kinect try the freenect stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1